# Wondering how twitter does people search

Tags: web-services, algorithm, twitter

I've noticed twitter people search can come up with some weird results. Searching for match in screen_name twitter_name and bio is obvious, but they also do something different. I guess it has something to do with [Triadic Closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triadic_closure) but find its usage for search (instead of suggestions) weird. Wanted to hear your thoughts about this issue.

Comment: Where do you get that they do something different?

Comment: @Chamilyan The results can be weird. e.g. don't have any mention of the searched keyword in the name/bio

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question might be a little nonspecific, but here are my thoughts:
Suppose your search query was "Miley Cyrus", for instance. Now the top results will for sure include her real account, then fake ones, but then the results will get a little distorted.

I expect it ranks each account / person `X` in this manner (or something similar):

`If person X follows accounts that has the search query in its bio / name, it has a higher rank than if that person didn't.`

In our search, "Rock Mafia" is a good example; it doesn't have the term "Miley Cyrus" in its bio nor its name, but if you look at the people "Rock Mafia" is following, you'll find a lot of "similar" names / bios. Another ranking criteria would be this:

`If person X has tweets that contains the search query in its content, it would also have a higher rank`

A good example is the result "AnythingDisney" (@adljupdated), you can see that the 4th most recent tweet contains "Miley".

So basically the search prioritization looks like this:

`Look in name / bio.`

`Need more results? Rank each person X by his followers and the people he follows, and by tweets that contain the query.`

`Need even more results? Look at "deeper" levels, rank each person X by the people being followed by the people X is following.`

`An so on, recursively.`

I hope this helped in any manner!

Comment: Thanks, helped. Regarding the Triadic Closure note, why is it a problem on twitter? Isn't that how they do "similar to" & "who to follow" ?

Comment: I'm glad it helped :) Well, after some thinking, I think that you might be right; the evaluation of the tie between two people indeed can be done by counting tweets in which they mention each other, or somesuch. I'll remove the note; I had something else in mind :)